# Part with marking code "ZO" "607"

Tags: identification, components

Can anyone please identify part with marking code "ZO" "607" it has 6 pins and I think the package is WLCSP.

[image: Part ZO 607]

Comment: Well, google seems to want to suggest it is a triac. (But, of course, the package doesn't match up.) Just FYI to others who might try a search.

Comment: please post a picture

Comment: Thank you all for your help.
This is a photo of the IC on a board.
[link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gWDSSXfc-_8hSezQ-uNlSN5nfPT8dlix/view)

Comment: may be you can search them here www.smdmarkingcodes.com for 【marking code】【smd code】

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it  be ZQ? From what I can see the pinout looks like it could match.

"MIC94165YCS - ZQ - 1.5mm × 1mm 6-Ball WLCSP" 
http://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/49e0c46145f1e0fbafdc3eb2279f6f3a5b83b03c/141mic9416x.pdf

Comment: looks like a 'Q' to me...

Comment: Thank you very very very... much @Narkeleptk. Yes it's match  perfectly. Size match, pin-out match and marking code is actually ZQ not ZO. I don't have microscope yet but after I took the picture I noticed that ZQ is a possibility, but I had no success finding the component either way. could you please tell me how did you find this component ?? Thank you again you made my day.

Comment: It just happened to pop up on google for me. I don't remember my search terms. I think it was just: WLCSP ZQ datasheet.